# deploy gives Failed to execute goal error

Tags: maven, build, tomcat7, pom.xml

You may have encountered the same error over somwhere else. I have tried a few configurations to build and deploy on tomcat. However, I am not sure where I am going wrong. And would appreciate some insight :
I am actually trying to build and deploy the war on tomcat.
I was trying to deploy the war file on the tomcat7.

I tried using maven for deploy, And I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project ABC: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project ABC: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    ... 22 more
```

This would be the settings.xml file in /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml

```
<server>
      <id>TomcatServer</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
```

Also, with the tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

This would be my pom.xml:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>OrbithubWeb</groupId>
  <artifactId>OrbithubWeb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <!--  added this codehaus plugin -->
    <finalName>OrbithubWeb</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>tomcat7</server>
            <path>/OrbithubWeb</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

      <!--  adding plugin for maven integration with tomcat, mojo -->
      <!--local deploy
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat7</server>
                    <path>/OrbithubWeb</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->
        <!--      
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>tomcat7</server>
          <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     -->

<!--  addedd this plugin for eclipse integration , date 21th may -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/tomcat-7.0.61</classpathContainer>
        </classpathContainers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

    </plugins>    
  </build>

  <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.61</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring framework just added ends here -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>


         <!--  jersey dependencies ends -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  jersey dependency ends -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- used for httpclient library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  adding for log4j dependency for logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: In your tomcat7-maven-plugin you are using http://localhost:8080/manager/ in the url should be http://localhost:8080/manager/text or you can remove if is localhost.

Comment: I made changes to the same, but could not resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using tomcat7-maven-plugin, you should take into account parameters in the configuration section.

**P.S** *`deploy` task in maven means upload artifacts (jar, war) to Repository Manger like Nexus, Artifactory and so on.*

pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!--local deploy-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat</server>
                    <path>/hello-webapp</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--remote deploy-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat</server>
                    <url>http://x.x.x.x:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <path>/hello-webapp</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>tomcat</id>
      <username>deploy</username>
      <password>123456</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>    
<tomcat-users>
      <role rolename="manager-script"/>
      <user username="deploy" password="123456" roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

At the end, run `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

Comment: which tomcat version are you using? 6.x 7.x 8.x?

Comment: I use a tomcat 7.0.61

Answer (score 0):

did you fix it?  if not, i think the fail is in setings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>TomcatServer</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

the  must be the same in tomcat7 in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        **<server>tomcat7</server>**
        <path>/OrbithubWeb</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```